# Looping through table columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is supposed to loop through all the tables in the database. It does that fine, I test it by outputting the table names.
But, I'm trying to loop through every column in the database so I could use it inside another query.

This is my current code, that loops through tables in the database:

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

if($link->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection died: ".$link->connect_error);
}

$showtables = $link->query("SHOW TABLES;");

foreach($showtables->fetch_all() as $table)
{
    printf($table[0] . "\n");

    // what i'm trying to achieve:
    foreach(/* ??? */ as $column)
    {
        printf("\t- ".$column."\n");
    }
}
?>
```

Could anyone lend their hand? Thank you!

Comment: But why? Incidentally, the information schema will give you all this without the need for any looping, but I still wonder why you'd want it!

Comment: @Strawberry I'm creating a script that loops through a 255 tables database and converts every column to LONGBLOB and then to UTF8MB4, because it's currently filled with gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

if($link->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection died: ".$link->connect_error);
}

$showtables = $link->query("DESCRIBE name_of_table;");

foreach($showtables->fetch_all() as $table)
{
    printf($table[0] . "\n");
}
```

If you want all the table in your database use this sql :

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_db'
order by table_name,ordinal_position
```

Comment: Not really, it just gives me the table's name instead of actually checking the table's columns!

Comment: can you make a var_dump on $showtables->fetch_all() just to know what is look like.

Comment: For example, on the xperience_stats table: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "xperience_stats"
}

Comment: Ok misunderstanding of my part. You want to find the column. So you have to change your query. I just edited my post.